# Async call from function, calling API

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm still learning about async.
I can't get my asynchro code to work. I have an fonction, that call an API.
I call this function on another function, to be able to manipulate later the data and merge them.
But my code always goes forward, without waiting the first function answer.
Async / promise problem

```
    var exchangeListing = { 
                        "exchange": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Kraken", 
                                            "pair": ['XBTUSD','XETHUSD']
                                          },{
                                            "name": "Coinbase", 
                                            "pair": ["BTC-USD","ETH-USDC"]
                                        },{
                                            "name":"Bittrex",
                                            "pair": ["BTC-USD","BTC-ETH"]
                                        }
                                    ]
                        }    

function BXgetPrice(currencies) {
    var ret;
    bittrex.getmarketsummary( { market : currencies}, function( data, err ) {
        if(data!=null) {
             ret = { 
                            message: { 
                                type: 'success', 
                                data: {
                                    last:data.result[0].Last,
                                    volume:data.result[0].Volume,
                                    date:data.result[0].TimeStamp,
                                }
                            }
                        };
            return ret;            
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}


//Loop to get all data from all exchanges we need, and merge in a JSON, to send to HTML page
function exchangeListe(exchangeListing) {
    var exchangeListing = JSON.stringify(exchangeListing);
    var exchangeListing = JSON.parse(exchangeListing);
    console.log(exchangeListing);
    for(var i = 0, len = exchangeListing.exchange.length; i < len; i++) {
        var a = exchangeListing.exchange[i].name;
        for(var j=0, l=exchangeListing.exchange[i].pair.length; j<l; j++) {
            if(a=="Kraken") {
                  //add code to manipulate data
            } else if(a=="Bittrex") {
                console.log("bittrex");
                BXgetPrice(exchangeListing.exchange[i].pair[j], function(data,err){
                    console.log("hi"+data);
                      //add code to manipulate data
                }) ;
            } else if(a=="Coinbase") {
                  //add code to manipulate data
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In Exchange list, i need my loop to do all the exchange available and all pair, get data from the API call, and merge them after.
For now, when launch, the exchangeListe(exchangeListing), i don't get the data from the function BXgetPrice. Data is empty.
I try to add the async function on both, and declare as const + use await, but nothing help, i that case i get Promise {}

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. Asynchronous call means that you do something (like send an AJAX request) and do not wait for it, your program keeps going when the result is not yet received. You expect your code to run in synchronous manner, but it is not. You could make your code synchronous, but it would be a bad idea, because then you are waiting for synchronous responses and your page might be frozen, which is bad UX. The right way to do this is to either call `exchangeListe` in your callback (the function which is passed to the asynchronous function is the callback, that is, it will be executed when the async job is done), or you could refactor your code and use promises instead, with equivalent results, but more elegant code.